# Access variables of sub in VBA

Tags: variables, vba, public

I have the following sub

```
Public Static Sub Varib()

Device_ = Sheet1.DeviceType_.Text
Model_ = Sheet1.Model_.Text
Security_ = Sheet1.SecurityGroup_.Text
Catagory_ = Application.Index(Worksheets("Temp_for_varible_lists").Range("b:b"), Application.Match(x, Worksheets("Temp_for_varible_lists").Range("A:A"), 0))

End Sub
```

It in fact carries on and in total produces a whole bunch of vaules of various datatypes based on the users input.

So the user choses from a few check boxes, list boxes, fills in some text boxes and hits a submit button and this sub populates a number of varibles from that, that are then uterlised by other funcation and sub in the application.

Now I could make all the varibles Global and access them in that fassion. But I was hoping for something more like what I have seen with c# and VB.net

where you can get the value by using

sub.varible name

example for the code above.

```
Sub Main()

x = Varib.Device_
msgbox(x)

end sub
```

is there a simmular way to do this in VBA?

Cheers

aaron

Comment: Use a class or a type.  You can pass the instance around as a parameter.

Comment: Why do your variable names end with an underscore?

Comment: only use an underscore as its become a habbit, a friend use to do it as he said it insured you dont accidently assigne a varible the same name as a existing function. But honestly just habbit these days

Comment: Well, it's a bad habit and you should get rid of it!

Comment: Why is it a bad habbit? What problems can it casue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking cannot be done. The solution is *not* to make your variables global either (generally a bad idea, with some exceptions, this case not being one of them).

One possibility is to create a user-defined type:

```
Type Varib
    Device_ As String
    Model_ As String
    Security_ As String
    Category_ As String
End Type
```

and a sub to populate it from your sheet:

```
Sub LoadVaribFromSheet(v As Varib)
    With v
        .Device_ = Sheet1.DeviceType_.Text
        .Model_ = Sheet1.Model_.Text
        .Security_ = Sheet1.SecurityGroup_.Text
        .Category_ = _
            Application.Index(Worksheets("Temp_for_varible_lists").Range("b:b"), _
            Application.Match(x, _
            Worksheets("Temp_for_varible_lists").Range("A:A"), 0))
    End With
End Sub
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myVarib As Varib
    LoadVaribFromSheet myVarib
    ' Now do stuff with myVarib ...
    MsgBox myVarib.Device_
End Sub
```

Comment: Now that sounds like what I need :) I deffently need to look more in to this side of things. And thank you for taking the time to write out the code. Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use encapsulation for this

```
Private value As String
Private value1 As String


Public Function setValue(val As String)
value = val
End Function

Public Function setValue1(val As String)
value1 = val
End Function


Public Function getValue() As String
getValue = value
End Function

Public Function getValue1() As String
getValue1 = value1
End Function

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Sub test()

MsgBox getValue & vbCrLf & getValue1

setValue "myValue"
setValue1 "myValue1"

MsgBox getValue & vbCrLf & getValue1
End Sub
```

Comment: yes but that would be lots of seperate functions. Unless I pass them all as different arguments to the same function. but it sill leaves the varibles outside the function.. oh hold on no it could all be wraped up in one fucntion cant it